# Can I make Chromium use font X every time CSS wants font Y?

Tags: fonts, chrome

For example, I would like to load FreeSans every time the style sheet specifies `font-famlily: Helvetica`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes you can. Go to your settings page and click advanced settings. Under "Web Content" section click the fonts button. Then at the bottom of the dialog box go to advanced font options.
This will take you to a Chrome plugin for advanced fonts / font scripts
here is a link if the link is not in the fonts section
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm</strike>

edit

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/styler/bogdgcfoocbajfkjjolkmcdcnnellpkb

this extension should work, sorry I thought it allowed custom scripts.

Comment: As far as I can understand, this lets me set my preferences based on scripts, while I would like to be able to do so based on font families.

Comment: updated answer, I thought the advanced settings allowed for a custom script as well.

Comment: Can you give me an example script that changes a typeface for another?

Comment: I've found [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee) that works with no need for scripts.

Comment: ...And I've found how to do it with a script with [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha): just like [here, with @font-face](https://gist.github.com/Hexcles/6325659)

Comment: I haven't time to answer at the moment, leaving a comment to try to remember later - and you can do this via `fontconfig`.